# Get working copy root path using pysvn

Tags: pysvn

When I run the SVN command 'svn info *path*', the SVN command line client (v1.8.4) spits out (among other things) a 'Working Copy Root Path'.

How would I get this same information using pysvn? Seems like it should be available using the either pysvn.Client.info() or pysvn.Client.info2(), but it doesn't seem to me that it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like, even nine years later, there's still no way to directly get the wc-root via pysvn.  The only way I've found to do it is with the `svn` command line client.  Something like:

```
def get_working_copy_root(path="."):
    return subprocess.check_output(["svn", "info", "--show-item", "wc-root", path]).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: I don't recall the exact context on why I asked this question nine years ago, but to the best of my recollection I ended up doing something similar to work around this. Thanks for the answer!